# type class Line does not name a type

Tags: c++, point

have a problem with types while assign, for example i have type point

```
class point:public pair<int, int>
{
    private: int index;
    public: point(int);

    point(int, int, int);

    int GetIndex();

    float GetDiff(point);

};

point::point(int Index): index(Index) {};

point::point(int x, int y, int Index): index(Index)
{
    first = x;
    second = y; 
}

int point::GetIndex()
{
    return index;
}

float point::GetDiff(point Point)
{
     return pow(pow(Point.first-first,2.0f) + pow(Point.second-second,2.0f),0.5f);
}
```

it's compile correct, and work well [i think)]
but when i want to use it, i get a error, it's code that use this class(point)

```
class Line
{
    public:
    Line();
    point firstPoint;
    point secondPoint;
};
Line::firstPoint = point(0); // i get error, same as on line 41
//and for example

struct Minimal
{
    Minimal();
    Line line();
    void SetFirstPoint(point p)
    {
        line.firstPoint = p;//41 line, tried point(p), same error. 
        UpdateDist();
    }
    void SetSecondPoint(point p)
    {
        line.secondPoint = p;
        UpdateDist();
    }
    void UpdateDist(void)
    {
        dist = line.firstPoint.GetDiff(line.secondPoint);
    }
    float dist;
};
```

and where is the error that give me gcc compiler

```
|41|error: 'firstPoint' in 'class Line' does not name a type|
```

Comment: Line line(); is a method not an object. On line 41, you tried to use it like an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that this line:

```
Line line();
```

Does not declare a member variable of type `Line`, but rather a function called `line` that returns an object of type `Line`. Therefore, either this code:

```
line.firstPoint = p;
```

Is meant to be as follows (which would make little sense, because you would be modifying a temporary):

```
line().firstPoint = p;
```

Or (most likely) the declaration above is just meant to be:

```
Line line; // Without parentheses
```

Moreover, the reason why you get an error here:

```
Line::firstPoint = point(0);
```

Is that `firstPoint` is not a `static` member variable of class `Line`. You first need an *instance* of `Line` whose `firstPoint` member you could modify.

Comment: ok) thanks, it works) but i have now: Minimal rez; i get: undefined reference to `Minimal::Minimal()'|, how to fix it?

Comment: @john: 1. Provide a definition for it (you are only declaring it); 2. I think you should really read an introductory book on C++ or some tutorial at least :-)

Comment: @john: Have a look at this list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list